# HTTP cookie won't save

Tags: vb.net, http, cookies, grapevine

Say I'm hosting my website from https://test.mycompany.com/app01/index.html. Index.html is my logon page. https://test.mycompany.com:10000 is my backend. Grapevine powers the backend. I set my cookie as follows:

```
Dim token As IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken = Nothing
Dim j As String = JWT.Serialize(FetchSetting("JWTKey"), String.Empty, String.Empty,
                                                                           ClaimsIdn, token, FetchSetting("GlobalTimeout"))
Dim AuthCookie As New Net.Cookie("Authorization", j) With {
                                                      .Expires = token.ValidTo,
                                                      .Path = "/",
                                                      .Domain = "test.mycompany.com"
                                                  }

Context.Response.Cookies.Add(AuthCookie)
```

When I log on, I monitor via the Chrome console. Logon returns 200. Under Network > (the logon POST request), I see a *Cookies* tab. I can also see a *Set-Cookie* header under the *Headers* tab (under *Response Headers*). Under Applications > Cookies, it's empty. If I were to paste that string into the console and set it to `document.cookie`, it'd set properly (and can see it from Applications > Cookies).

Comment: Setting a cookie is working fine in Grapevine. When I do this: `context.Response.Cookies.Add(new Cookie("test", "working"));`, the cookie shows up in the Google Chrome console for me. There might be something in the way the cookie is being generated?

Comment: I've tested it with just creating a new cookie, to keep it simple, like `New Net.Cookie("Name", "Value")`. Same result. I'm wondering if CORS has something to do with it. If there was a way to debug and see what CORS was doing, perhaps silently rejecting it (due to domain/path/port).

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with CORS:

> Two URLs have the same origin if the protocol, port (if specified), and host are the same for both. You may see this referenced as the "scheme/host/port tuple", or just "tuple". (A "tuple" is a set of items that together comprise a whole — a generic form for double/triple/quadruple/quintuple/etc.)
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

The CORS feature is still being implemented in Grapevine as of 4.1.1, meanwhile there is a discussion on work-arounds that can be found here:

https://github.com/sukona/Grapevine/issues/86